# Grab the Name of a selected checkbox

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I'm trying to do something that would be really simple in any other language but after about an hour of searching online I can't find how to do it in Vba. Basically I have a checkbox which when clicked should assign its Name to a variable and display the name in a message box. My actual function is much larger but this is the only bit that I need assistance on.

```
    Private Sub admin_toggle_Click()

    Dim admin_group As String
    Dim admin_name As String
    Dim admin_value As String


    admin_name = ActiveControl.Name
    MsgBox admin_name

    End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. All it keeps doing is returning the name of the frame in which the checkboxes are encased.

Comment: Yes. I should have guessed that this is related to your last question :) You are correct. if the checkbox is in a frame then `ActiveControl.Name` will always return the frame name in such a case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as follows:

```
 Private Sub admin_toggle_Click() 

Dim admin_group As String 
Dim admin_name As String 
Dim admin_value As String 


admin_name = admin_frame.ActiveControl.Name 
MsgBox admin_name 

End Sub
```

Because the checkbox I was referring to was contained within a frame, I had to reference the encasing frame before accessing the element I needed.